Invalid subquery: Scalar subquery must return only one column
When i run this query in data bricks i get the following error

[INVALID_SUBQUERY_EXPRESSION.SCALAR_SUBQUERY_RETURN_MORE_THAN_ONE_OUTPUT_COLUMN] Invalid subquery: Scalar subquery must return only one column, but got 3. SQLSTATE: 42823

`select 
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c
from    com a11
    join    fam_grp a12
      on    ((a11.mkt_id || a11.brd_id) = (a12.mkt_id || a12.brd_id) and 
    a11.dataset = a12.dataset)
where   ((a11.cust_id,
    a11.mkt_id,
    a11.o_cust_id)
 in (((select   pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id
    from    ZZMD00  pc21
    group by    pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id)
 intersect (select  pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id
    from    ZZMD01  pc21
    group by    pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id)))
 and a11.dataset in ('C'))
group by    
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c`

I believe i get the issue after the where clause using a sub query, i guess that is causing the error.

Can you provide the results of the query you want?

If possible, also provide the table structure used. I see here that the query is less optimal and in the future, it will affect the query speed.

@kurniadi445 the result should be multiple columns as in select statement used.
i find i get the issue mostly after where

The error message seems to be self-explanatory. If you don’t want to restructure your query you’d need to split your subquery into 3 subqueries, 1 per column

i get the following error Whose error message is this, who generated it? There is no such error message in MySQL 8.0 Error Message Reference...

please only use the mysql tag for mysql questions

You can't use row-comparators in your DBMS, so IN with multiple columns doesn't work.
You need to use EXISTS with either INTERSECT or an inner WHERE filter.
Also, given that you are using an EXISTS or IN, using GROUP BY in the subquery doesn't make much sense anyway.
select 
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c
from com a11
join fam_grp a12
  on a11.mkt_id = a12.mkt_id
 and a11.brd_id = a12.brd_id
 and a11.dataset = a12.dataset
where exists (
    select
        a11.cust_id,
        a11.mkt_id,
        a11.o_cust_id

    intersect

    select
        pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id
    from ZZMD00 pc21

    intersect
    
    select
        pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id
    from ZZMD01 pc21
  )
  and a11.dataset in ('C')
group by    
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c;

Alternatively
select 
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c
from com a11
join fam_grp a12
  on a11.mkt_id = a12.mkt_id
 and a11.brd_id = a12.brd_id
 and a11.dataset = a12.dataset
where exists (select 1
    from ZZMD00 pc21
    where a11.cust_id = pc21.cust_id
      and a11.mkt_id = pc21.mkt_id
      and a11.o_cust_id = pc21.o_cust_id

    intersect
    
    select
        pc21.cust_id,
        pc21.mkt_id_1,
        pc21.o_cust_id
    from ZZMD01 pc21
  )
  and a11.dataset in ('C')
group by    
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c;

You can also do this as separate where predicates.
select 
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c
from com a11
join fam_grp a12
  on a11.mkt_id = a12.mkt_id
 and a11.brd_id = a12.brd_id
 and a11.dataset = a12.dataset
where exists (select 1
    from ZZMD00 pc21
    where a11.cust_id = pc21.cust_id
      and a11.mkt_id = pc21.mkt_id
      and a11.o_cust_id = pc21.o_cust_id
)
  and exists (select 1
    from ZZMD01 pc21
    where a11.cust_id = pc21.cust_id
      and a11.mkt_id = pc21.mkt_id
      and a11.o_cust_id = pc21.o_cust_id
)
  and a11.dataset in ('C')
group by    
    all.a,
    all.b,
    all.c;

I'm not sure why you are concatting mkt_id and brd_id, but it's unlikely to be correct or performant.

Looks like it's actually Spark SQL, and OP has posted on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/1cqauzj/invalid_subquery_scalar_subquery_must_return_only/

will this not work in databricks @Charlieface

I don't know, did you try it?

yes sir, but it is loading for a very long time running till now

I guess you need to look at indexing

when i remove the entire where section below query runs and loads.

See new edit, you can do it as separate where filters. You need to look at the query plan and work out what's taking the extra time.
